# Mechanism of working of full wave rectifier using center tapped transformer

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I am self learning semiconductors for past few days and i couldnot get the answer to the following question.

**How does a centre tap transformer rectifier function?**

[image]

I could not quite get to understand what is the role of centre tap in this case and how does it help to generate full wave fluctuating dc current. I had checked the english wikipedia page regarding this but that does not seem to explain the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose for the center tap is to eliminate the need for the two extra diodes (total of four diodes) one would need in a full wave bridge to do the same thing (rectify each half of the wave so that a positive pulse is available twice per single incoming wave). Specifically, full wave rectification means the positive half of the incoming wave is available as positive voltage at the output, and the negative half of the incoming wave is also available as positive voltage at the output--so you get two positive pulses for each single incoming wave.

The center tap helps because it makes it possible to rectify each half of the incoming wave with a single diode. If you consider the center tap as the common ground (place the black lead of a voltmeter on it), you'll see that the two other secondary leads take turns going positive, first one then the other for a single input wave. So a diode on each of those leads produces a positive pulse, and you get positive pulses twice for each single incoming wave, and so you have full wave rectification.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.but i could not get as to why the two diodes receive opposite waveforms for each half ac wave.how the center tap helps in this regard?

Comment: If the ground of an oscilloscope is on the center tap, the wave seen on one of the remaining secondary leads will be opposite the wave seen on the other. So when one is positive the other is negative, and vice versa.

Comment: what do you mean oscillioscope?can you explain a bit more clearly.thanks.

Comment: An oscilloscope is just a voltmeter that has a video display that shows a graph of the voltage over time. In other words, it shows a waveform.

Comment: yes that's precisely what the instrument will show.but why it happens so?

Comment: If you connect the ground lead from your oscilloscope to the center tap of the transformer, then your first graph represents the scope display if the positive lead is connected at the top of the transformer, and the second graph shows the display if connected to the top of the resistor.

Comment: When the 'top' end of the transformer secondary is positive with respect to the centre tap, the bottom end is negative with respect to the centre tap. Therefore D1 conducts but D2 doesn't. All this reverses on the next half cycle. So one of the diodes conducts on every half cycle, a different diode on each half cycle.

Comment: This centre tap full wave system was commonplace up until some fifty years ago, because in those days diodes were bulkier and quite expensive. Often thermionic diodes (valves or tubes) were used. Now that diodes are small and cheap, it is cheaper to use a bridge rectifier of 4 diodes (often integrated in a single package) than a centre-tapped transformer and two diodes.